# Foreign Array Marshall Ptr Ptr in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell, marshalling, ffi

I am trying to create a list of lists, or a [[b]] from a Ptr Ptr b, passed in from C code via the FFI. So, essentially creating a list of lists from a two dimensional C array.

My logic entails applying peekArray to the Ptr Ptr b, first getting a [Ptr b], then applying peekArray to each element in that [Ptr b], to obtain the [[b]].

My first call to peekArray seems to give me the [Ptr b] without a problem, but when I try to process each of the Ptr b in that list, Haskell gives me an error:

Couldn't match expected type '[t0]' with actual type 'IO [a0]'
In the return type of a call of 'peekArray'

I am using peekArray the same way for both calls, just performing it on the list elements the second time:

```
c <- peekArray q n
```

Is there some extra step that I need to take?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
\x y ptr -> join $ fmap (mapM (peekArray y)) (peekArray x ptr)
```

or

```
\x y ptr -> do 
  xs <- peekArray x ptr
  join $ mapM (peekArray y) xs
```

The type is `Storable a => Int -> Int -> Ptr (Ptr a) -> IO [[a]]`, I believe that is what you wanted.